# SVN error"access to '/svn/myservice/!svn/act/d99e498e-9a8d-374c-a3e4-fde21198bfa2' forbidden"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I cannot commit but I can update.

When I attempt to commit I get the following error:

> access to
>   '/svn/myservice/!svn/act/d99e498e-9a8d-374c-a3e4-fde21198bfa2'
>   forbidden

I'm using Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: I still haven't got it right.

Comment: I was able to resolve this based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937159/svn-erroraccess-to-svn-myservice-svn-act-d99e498e-9a8d-374c-a3e4-fde21198bfa2/6470530#6470530

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43204615/5466401

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This happens when you check out a repository and the casing in the repository path that you typed does not match the actual repository path. When the casing does not match you're able to check out the repo but you get that error when you commit.

However, it can also occur when the name of your SVN account is entered with the wrong capitalization when making the commit (e.g., "Username: Joe" instead of "Username: joe").

Comment: I use Tortoise SVN with Visual SVN Server on a Windows Server machine. It turned out, the repo URL is case sensitive even in a Windows environment. With the wrong casing, I was able to check out the code but when I commit, it threw the above error. I changed the URL to the correct casing and it worked.

Comment: Can't believe the wrong case can cause this. It's funny.Thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: Had this issue too, casing is at fault. I'd be interested to know if this is a bug in Tortoise or with the underlying SVN binaries (I've experienced the issue with Tortoise 64-bit and Subversion Edge server for Windows)

Comment: For the subversion newbies out there (like me) if you're using TortoiseSVN, you can change the case of the svn URL, by doing an SVN Relocate on the root local folder.

Comment: Thanks! I was putting in my username wrong. Had to capitalize it.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem.

I solved it on my Windows XP by

- Clearing the authentication data that Tortoise had saved. Then,
- Re-tried the commit

Tortoise, then, asked me for my login credentials. After re-inserting my username and password, the commit worked.

How do you clear the authentication data that Tortoise had saved?

[Quote:](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2006-08/0210.shtml)

> - On the PC go to Tortoise SVN > Settings > Saved Data > Authentication Data
> - Click [Clear]
>
> That will clear the stored information, and you will be prompted for
>   it the next time it's needed.

Comment: This solved it only partly for me. Every time I save the authentication the error comes up again :/.

Answer (score 4):

In some case, the error
  "`access to '/svn/myservice/!svn/act/d99e498e-9a8d-374c-a3e4-fde21198bfa2' forbidden`"

should be caused by the letter case of url, for example, as the following Repo directory:     `E:\SVNRepo\MyService`

if you get the SVN with url: `http://..../svn/myservice` , you can checkout/update, but the commit should cause the "`forbidden`" error.

Relocate local work folder to "`http://..../svn/MyService`" , every thing should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

it can also happen with, when you checkout with a user, that does not have write permissions. With the cli provide --username with a user that has write permissions.

Comment: This was similar to my issue. I ended up having to clear my .subversion settings to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Update is a READ / PULL, Commit is a WRITE / PUSH.

I was using Linux with Apache and come to find out it was with the Repo breakdown in file used for the `AuthzSVNAccessFile /x/x/x/x/users-access-file`

`FILE CONTENTS of /x/x/x/x/users-access-file`

```
[groups]
DEV =  user1,user2

[/]
* = r

[blah_blah:/]
@DEV = rw
```

My problem was I 1st had this: `[blah_blah]`, when I changed it to `[blah_blah:/]`
That fixed MY problem. Simple Typo, causes Huge headaches tracking it down.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "write" permissions in that folder

I was working with GitHub and it wouldn't work until I checked the repository permissions again and noticed I've "READ" access.

Answer (score 0):

My repository gave this error with: !svn/act/{guid}' forbidden", im using windows 7 64bit too.

It turned out to be that 'syntax check' was set to yes. so changed it to no and all worked fine.

now, what does syntax check do I wonder?

nothing to do with the case of the url though, tried that first!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using the url like "**https://exampleIP.com/svn/myrepo/**"
while searching on Internet I found that svn commit is **case sensitive**, so enter the exact url as it is defined. I was entering "**MyRepo**" as "**myrepo**" that was the issue, now I committed the code successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Try to commit with user name:

```
svn commit --username your_user_name
```

Or with repo url:

```
svn commit --username your_user_name https://your_repo_url
```