# Error:access to '/svn/path/' forbidden - Not a case issue

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2003

I have a developer in another country who is accessing svn from there.
Now we had an issue with the firewall, and he could not access the repository for a while. The firewall error should be fixed now, and it works again for others. This devs gets the error "*Error:access to '/svn/path/lots-of-numbers' forbidden*" though.
When I tried to find the cause, I found this: [link to similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937159/svn-erroraccess-to-svn-myservice-svn-act-d99e498e-9a8d-374c-a3e4-fde21198bfa2)
However, he sent me the repository link he uses, and it is all in lower case, just as it should be. The permissions are also correct, I just double checked them.

Could the problem lie in the firewall somehow, or does anyone have another suggestion?

Comment: Are you using the http access to svn? In this case would be very interesting if you include some part of the error or access logs when this developer try to access..

Comment: Did your svn accout has read and write permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out some time ago, but I guess I should post this here too in case someone else has a similar issue. My problem was actually with permission settings.
What I have now that works, are the exact same settings I had in the svn server previously, only now they are inherited from the root. Sooo...yeah. I have no idea why that actually made a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue for a while and figured out what was wrong.  I had a capital where I shouldn't have.  My repository was svn/dave, but i had it in the URL as svn/Dave.  It let me log in without any issues, but I couldn't actually do anything.  Changing it to lower case cleared everything up.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation and I also had changed the permission in the server to inherit from the root.

My problem got solved after I issued the command `svn update`

Usually it is a practice that I always follow - I run `svn status .` and then `svn update .` before firing `svn commit`.

I skipped `svn update` this time and caught the error.

It looks like `svn update` does much more than just update the files.