# Access to repository '/dir/!svn/act/b724faeb-c0a7-c144-9f2e-9e2e9c882cfc' forbidden when using commit

Tags: svn

I am using svn on command line(DOS) in windows as svnTortoise is not on my system.

I have downloaded the files from the repository using C:/>svn https://dir.svn.application.com

and made changes in the directory. Now when I am going to commit the files using

`C:/dir/application/lib>svn commit`
I got the error `Access to repository '/dir/!svn/act/b724faeb-c0a7-c144-9f2e-9e2e9c882cfc' forbidden.`

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937159

Comment: I have done all the steps given in the post stackoverflow.com/questions/5937159 but still the forbidden access message appears

Comment: Can you show us *exactly* what you typed, using the real paths, the exact capitalization, and the errors returned by svn ?