# Cornerstone and Terminal throwing errors with subversion

Tags: svn, terminal, versioning, cornerstone

i've been browsing around the past two hours for a solution but to no avail. i've used git the past few months and have liked it, but just inherited a project that uses SVN.

i checked out a copy just fine last week. today i went to commit and had issues. i tried using Cornerstone as well as basic Terminal command lines. both pushback and won't allow me to commit these files.

[this thread seemed promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937159/svn-erroraccess-to-svn-myservice-svn-act-d99e498e-9a8d-374c-a3e4-fde21198bfa/6470530#6470530)

but from all that i can tell i have no casing discrepancies (aside: is there any way besides svn info and eyeballing to figure this out? maybe i've done my double checking incorrectly)

this is what i get in terminal:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: access to '/pra-003-11/!svn/act/74c82fe8-1606-4a70-a2ae-26cf6bd595f5' forbidden
```

and Cornerstone says this:

> OPTIONS of 'https://myurl.svn.beanstalkapp.com/pra-003-11/trunk': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://myurl.svn.beanstalkapp.com)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

and while i've got you here: would anyone say just move over to GIT? is it worth the trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get "Could not authenticate to server" it means exactly this problem: you can't **correctly authenticate themselves** on commit. If you didn't get auth-prompt it can means only one - you have stored credentials for this repo and they are wrong

You can:

- remove outdated credentials and auth by hand at least once
- use `--username` and `--passsword` options for command

Comment: it allows me to login with the creds i'm using so it doesn't seem to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

i spoke with beanstalk support and it ends up that the project manager hadn't granted me proper access :p