# Access to '/svn/ctm/!svn/me' forbidden When commit to svn server?

Tags: svn

I can check out from the svn server, but i can't commit changes. Error messages are shown as follows:

> Access to '/svn/repo/!svn/me' forbidden

[Screenshot of the error](http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/mw690/afba20ebgw1e3cng9gz8oj.jpg)

To solve this problem, i have searched the internet while there's no userful solution found.

Here is something about my svn server deployed on apache:

- OS: windows 7 32bits;
- server: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) SVN/1.7.8    PHP/5.4.3
  mod_wsgi/3.5-BRANCH Python/2.7.3 DAV/2.

Comment: The URL is case-sensitive, so double-check that you use correct URL.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue quite recently and found two things:

1. You've run out of space on the drive the repo is on. SVN fails with an access forbidden message then.
2. There's a permissions problem preventing access, you need to chmod through it.

Comment: chmod? it's definitely authz (path-based authorization) issue. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

Comment: Well it depends entirely on whether he could check in to the branch prior to the problem. I had the same issue and it turned out to be permissions.

Comment: @Nicholas Smith Thanks for your answer, but: 1.I have enough space. 2.This seems to be the most possible reason, but i have no idea how to manage folder permission on windows...The service list on windows task manager shows that Httpd.exe belongs to `SYSTEM` and `SYSTEM` has full permissions to the Repo folder. But this error still exists...

Comment: @bahrep Thanks for your answer. I did not use the authz part, config is as follows:`<Location /svn/><br />
Dav svn
SVNParentPath "e:/svn/"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My SVN"
SVNListParentPath on
AuthUserFile "e:/svn/passwd"
#AuthzSVNAccessFile "e:/svn/authz"
Require valid-user
</Location>`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same Problem, and the solution was in the Pathname and Case. I checked some Projects out, and on the checkout I type a single Letter of the path with the wrong case:

Something like this:
- http://svn.enterprise.org/svn/Repo/trunk/... (while I should have typed "repo", and not "Repo").

I could then make a "svn up" or "svn co" w/o problems. But when commiting (back to "Repo") the apache module, which check if I have write permission only knows the path "repo", and thus the error message.

My solution was to delete everything and checking out again with the right case in the SVN-URL. (svn switch could also works, the the Typo is far to the right)

Comment: There is another thread on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937159/svn-erroraccess-to-svn-myservice-svn-act-d99e498e-9a8d-374c-a3e4-fde21198bfa

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you set the read/write permissions in the user access file, e.g.

```
user1 = rw
user2 = rw
```

etc. for every user in the authz file, e.g.

```
/etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
```

when using

```
AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
```

in

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue due to user access permission.

I work with 2 more software developers and have this issue long time due to access to repositories with AD user configuration. When every 3 months change password the past password are cache in Visual SVN Manager. Then get this error of !svn/me

We change SVN Manager to don't use AD system and then we don't have more problems.